# pyspark add a column in dataframe with json

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe df3 :-

test_df3.show()

```
+----------------------+-------------------+

|count(user_name)|count(team_id)|

+----------------------+-------------------+

| 10 | 10|

+----------------------+-------------------+
```

I need to create a json from above two columns & add to it to a new column

```
udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x,y: {"user_count":x, "team_count":y}, StringType())
```

above I am taking StringType as json_type is not available,

```
test_df3 = test_df3.withColumn("new",udf(col("count(user_name)"), col("count(team_id)"))).select("new")
```

## Any help about how to get json in dataframe column.

Comment: You are looking for [`to_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

Comment: @philantrovert thanks man, it worked..only limitation is that it only works with struct type

Comment: Well yeah, since it's nested and complex.

Comment: This SO answer has what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436292/1933651