# Pyspark merge multiple columns into a json column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I asked the question a while back for python, but now I need to do the same thing in PySpark.

I have a dataframe (df) like so:

```
|cust_id|address    |store_id|email        |sales_channel|category|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|1234567|123 Main St|10SjtT  |idk@gmail.com|ecom         |direct  |
|4567345|345 Main St|10SjtT  |101@gmail.com|instore      |direct  |
|1569457|876 Main St|51FstT  |404@gmail.com|ecom         |direct  |
```

and I would like to combine the last 4 fields into one metadata field that is a json like so:

```
|cust_id|address    |metadata                                                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1234567|123 Main St|{'store_id':'10SjtT', 'email':'idk@gmail.com','sales_channel':'ecom', 'category':'direct'}   |
|4567345|345 Main St|{'store_id':'10SjtT', 'email':'101@gmail.com','sales_channel':'instore', 'category':'direct'}|
|1569457|876 Main St|{'store_id':'51FstT', 'email':'404@gmail.com','sales_channel':'ecom', 'category':'direct'}   |
```

Here's the code I used to do this in python:

```
cols = [
    'store_id',
    'store_category',
    'sales_channel',
    'email'
]

df1 = df.copy()
df1['metadata'] = df1[cols].to_dict(orient='records')
df1 = df1.drop(columns=cols)
```

but I would like to translate this to PySpark code to work with a spark dataframe; I do NOT want to use pandas in Spark.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use **`to_json`** function to create json object!

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#sample data
df=spark.createDataFrame([('1234567','123 Main St','10SjtT','idk@gmail.com','ecom','direct')],['cust_id','address','store_id','email','sales_channel','category'])

df.select("cust_id","address",to_json(struct("store_id","category","sales_channel","email")).alias("metadata")).show(10,False)

#result
+-------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|cust_id|address    |metadata                                                                                |
+-------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1234567|123 Main St|{"store_id":"10SjtT","category":"direct","sales_channel":"ecom","email":"idk@gmail.com"}|
+-------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**`to_json by passing list of columns:`**

```
ll=['store_id','email','sales_channel','category']

df.withColumn("metadata", to_json(struct([x for x in ll]))).drop(*ll).show()

#result
+-------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|cust_id|address    |metadata                                                                                |
+-------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1234567|123 Main St|{"store_id":"10SjtT","email":"idk@gmail.com","sales_channel":"ecom","category":"direct"}|
+-------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: is it possible to pass in lists for the columns instead of their actual column names?

Comment: Best answer ever! I'm going from Kafka -> Spark -> Kafka and this answer is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

@Shu gives a good answer, here's a variant that works out slightly better for my use case. I'm going from Kafka -> Spark -> Kafka and this one liner does exactly what I want. The `struct(*)` will pack up all the fields in the dataframe.

```py
# Packup the fields in preparation for sending to Kafka sink
kafka_df = df.selectExpr('cast(id as string) as key', 'to_json(struct(*)) as value')
```